# Is it possible to create a case class where one field is dependent on another?

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a case class.

```
case class A(x: Int)
```

I need to introduce another variable `y` which is dependent on `x`, say `x/2`.

Can I write something like this:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: Int = x/2)
```

If no what is the ideal solution?

Comment: If you already have `x`, and `y` depends on `x`, why do you want to have it as an additional variable? You can still construct it from `x`, no?

Comment: Why not add an auxiliary `apply`-factory method to the companion object? Or do you want to use `case A(x, y) => ` in `match`-expressions? Or what is the point of having two variables in the first place, if they store essentially the same information anyway?

Answer (score 6):

```
case class A(x: Int) {
  val y = x / 2
}
```

Example use:

```
val a = A(10)
a.x    // 10
a.y    // 5
```

Edit: if you must have `y` in your arguments then you can overload the apply function in a companion object:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: Int)

object A {
  def apply(x: Int): A = new A(x, x / 2)
}
```

You can use this as before with `A(10)` but note that you will be able to call the default apply method with something like `A(10, 11)`.

Comment: I would need a spray json protocol for the same, with two fields. for the same class. Earlier it was  'jsonFormat1(A.apply). How to change that now ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have two argument lists:

```
 case class Foo(bar: Int)(val baz: Int = bar/2)
```

The downside is, you have to specify the second list, even when it is empty: `Foo(2)` does not work, has to be `Foo(2)()`.

A bigger problem (same one as exists with the `case class Foo(x: Int) { val y = x / 2 }` approach) is that the second `val`isn't like the first one:

```
Foo(2)().toString // returns "Foo(2)"
Foo(2)().productArity  // returns 1 (not 2)
Foo(2)().productIterator.toList // returns List(2)
```

You can still reference the second variable explicitly, like `println(Foo(2)().baz)` (prints 1), but none of the usual case-class stuff works. Even `Foo(2)(1) == Foo(2)(4)` will return true :(

So, your best option is overloading the `apply` method as suggested in the other answer.